# text box autocomplete not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, forms, autocomplete, window

I am facing problem while work on text box autocomplete in window form application. my collection show 50 records on search. but i receive only 2 in textbox suggestion. why? see code .I am doing this work in txtInput_TextChanged event.

```
private void txtInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = txtInput.Text.ToString();
        dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = "MedicineName like '%" + str + "%'";
        for (int i = 0; i < dv.Count; i++)
        {
            string name = dv[i]["MedicineName"].ToString();
            nameCollection.Add(name);
        }
        txtInput.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        txtInput.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        txtInput.AutoCompleteCustomSource = nameCollection;
        //textboxMedicine.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        //textboxMedicine.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
    }
```

I also set autocomplete and autocompletesource in property window. but still my textbox autocomplete suggestions not working correctly. please help

Answer (score 0):

Use this `AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend` for `AutoCompleteMode`

```
txtInput.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
```

### EDIT:

Change `like` to `LIKE`

```
dv.RowFilter = "MedicineName LIKE '%"+str+"%'";
```

Comment: no change by using autocompletemode.suggestappend .this suggest and append result but problem is that i want to see all list of records.for this time only 3 displayed

Comment: @AbdulWaheed: I have doubt at your rowfilter. Change `like` to `LIKE`

Comment: Siava, sorry but does't make any change. I see 42 items in nameCollection while debugging.but i receive only 3,4 items in my suggestions. why? i change my filter but make no difference. as you see items are added after filtration happen in data view.

Comment: i see AutoCompleteMode.Suggest not show same records. its only suggest unique entries but i need to suggest every record. how i can fix this.